# Unable to show error message on table with the Invalid search data (no data from API, gives 404)

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

Able to populate data while API gives the response, if API fails to give the response please help me how to show the error message like "No results found" in table.I tried below and please refer working stackblitz.

```
const dataUrl =
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data3.json"; //invalid API

const dataUrl =
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json"; // ---- valid API
    
        this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(response => {
          this.persons = response.data.map(x => ({
            ...x,
            check: false,
            test: x.firstName
          }));
          this.dtTrigger.next();
        });
      }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invalid-api-response?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Check out my answer. Please mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the subscribe function is the error callback.

You can do the following:

```
this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(response => {
          this.persons = response.data.map(x => ({
            ...x,
            check: false,
            test: x.firstName
          }));
          this.dtTrigger.next();
        }, errResponse => {
          // Your error display logic here.
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, **add** two variables:

```
noDataErrorMessage = "No results found";
isCalledAPI = false;
```

**Change** the HTTP API calling as:

```
this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.persons = response.data.map(x => ({
          ...x,
          check: false,
          test: x.firstName
        }));
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      },
      () => {
        if (!this.isCalledAPI) this.isCalledAPI = true;
      }
    );
```

Which will set the status if you called the API.

Finally, add in HTML after table:

```
<p *ngIf="isCalledAPI && !persons.length" style="text-align:center">{{ noDataErrorMessage }}</p>
```

**This message will be shown when you are using a wrong URL or valid URL with no data.**

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invalid-api-response-bxzkvu?file=app/app.component.html).